# Sorting an array with Bi Predicate

Tags: java, sorting

I was trying to take a sorted `File[]` array (With a certain sorting condition that was applied to it) 
and I tried to apply an extra sort to different objects that had similar sorting results from the first sort (In example - file size).

I wrote the following code, but It didn't work:

```
private static void sameValueHandler(File[] orderedFiles, BiPredicate<File,File> sortingCondition){ 
        for(int i = 0; i < orderedFiles.length - 1; i++){
            int j;
            for (j = i + 1; j < orderedFiles.length ; j++){
                if (!sortingCondition.test(orderedFiles[i],orderedFiles[j])){
                    if (j - i - 1> 1){
                        File[] sameFiles = new File[j - i - 1];
                       System.arraycopy(orderedFiles, i, sameFiles, 0,j - i - 1);
                       sameFiles = MainOrder.defaultOrd(sameFiles); // Calls a method that sorts (files by file.getAbsolutePath())

                       System.arraycopy(sameFiles, 0, orderedFiles, i,j - i - 1);
                   }else{
                       break;
                   }
                }
            }
            i = j;

        }
    }
```

Basically, All im trying to do, is to check which files from `orderedFiles` share the same `sortingCondition` from the given BiPredicate, and sort these files with `MainOrder.defaultOrd()` which sorts by `file.getAbsolutePath()`, so the results should be a sorted array that was sorted intially with the given BiPredicate (assume that `File[] orderedFiles` is already sorted) - and then resort the files that share the same sortingCondition AGAIN with the deafaultOrd method while keeping the original files that had a unique sortingCondition result in place.

For example:

Lets say I have the following files in `orderedFiles`:

-file2.txt

-file1.txt

-file5.txt

-file6.txt

and file1 and file2 share the same fileSize, but `file2.getAbsolutePath().compareTo(file1.getAbsolutePath()) > 0`

I would want to resort the array such that file2 will appear after file1:

-file1.txt

-file2.txt

-file5.txt

-file6.txt

Hope I was clear enough. thanks!

edit:

Also tried using bubble sort, but it didn't work aswell:

```
 private static void sameValueHandler(File[] orderedFiles, BiPredicate<File,File> sortingCondition){
        //TODO fix.
        int arrLength = orderedFiles.length;
        for(int i = 0; i<arrLength-1; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<arrLength-i-1;j++){
                if(sortingCondition.test(orderedFiles[j],orderedFiles[j+1])){
                    if(orderedFiles[j].getAbsolutePath().compareTo(orderedFiles[j+1].getAbsolutePath()) > 0){
                        File temp = orderedFiles[j];
                        orderedFiles[j] = orderedFiles[j+1];
                        orderedFiles[j+1] = temp;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator)` with the following `Comparator` to sort first on file length and then on file path (in case file lengths are equal):

```
File[] files = ...;
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        int result = Long.compare(f1.length(), f2.length());
        if(result == 0) {
            result = f1.getAbsolutePath().compareTo(f2.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm really trying to work this while using the BiPredicate functional interface. 

Mind taking a look at my bubble sort and see why that didn't work out?

Answer (score 0):

First you must understand how comparator works ([from Java docs](http://web.archive.org/web/20090126135350/http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html)):

```java
if file1 > file2, it returns positive number  
if file1 < file2, it returns negative number  
if file1 == file2, it returns 0
```

Saying that:

```java
    public static Comparator<File> secondSort = (f1, f2) -> {
        // apply the second sort rules and return -1, 0, 1 based on Comparator returns
        return 0; // -1, 0, 1
    };

    public static Comparator<File> sortIt = (f1, f2) -> {
        // check if files are equals base in your first rule
        boolean filesAreEquals = true;

        if (filesAreEquals) {
            return secondSort.compare(f1, f2);
        }
        return 0;
    };

    private static void sameValueHandler(File[] orderedFiles) 
    {        
        List<File> ordered = Arrays.
                stream(orderedFiles).
                sorted(sortIt::compare).
                collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

It allows you to pass different comparators to your method and change the way elements are ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single sort.  You need to sort your array as follows:

```
    Arrays.sort(orderedFiles,
                Comparator.comparing(File::length)
                        .thenComparing(
                                File::getAbsolutePath));
```

The second argument to `Arrays.sort` is a `comparator` which you can read about in the JavaDocs.

First it sorts on the length and if they are equals it sorts on the path.  You can chain as many `thenComparing` methods as you need to.  It is of minimal consequence if the file has already been sorted on the first field.  It will still work just fine. Or you can do it as follows:

```
     Arrays.sort(orderedFiles,
             Comparator.comparing(File::getAbsolutePath));
                        .
```

Here is an example of it working on some made up data.  When you run it and print out the sorted list you can see how it sorts on the `value` first and then then `length` of the name.

```
        List<Example> data = new ArrayList<>(
                List.of(new Example(20, "watermelon"),
                        new Example(20, "apple"),
                        new Example(20, "peaches"),
                        new Example(10, "grapes"),
                        new Example(100, "house"),
                        new Example(100, "apartment")));
        data.sort(Comparator.comparing(Example::getValue)
                .thenComparing(a -> a.getName().length()));

        data.forEach(System.out::println);



    class Example {
        private int value;
        private String name;

        public Example(int value, String name) {
            this.value = value;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return value + " " + name;
        }
```